# How to make font within equations look normal

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, overleaf, emphasis, italic-correction

When writing maths equations and I want to write words within the dollar signs, or between when I've written `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` it comes out in italics. I have tried `\emph{...}` but it still come out in italics. Any suggestions? I am using `\usepackage{amsmath}` and I'm writing my document on Overleaf.

Thank you.

Comment: \text{} seems to be the command you are looking for.

Comment: @leandriis thank you, that works perfectly :))

Comment: You want `\textnormal`. If you use `\text` when the surrounding text is italic (such as in a theorem statement), or bold (such as a title) it will inherit that formatting.

Comment: Note that. if you’re doing this within a title fornatted with `\mathbf\boldmath` you might want to match the weight of the surrounding text. You can switch from Italics to upright, but match the current font weight, with `\textup`.